# Css and jquery background color changing

Tags: jquery, css

Here i have some example and the same code in 1.case dont work but in 2.case work. Why that?

So I need to work in 1.case just like buttons work in 2.case.

Here is js code: http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/8/

```
$(".ca_button, .ca_button1,.button").click(function () {

    var t = $(this);

    $par = t.parent();

    $par.find(".ca_button, .ca_button1").css("background-color", "#bababa");

    if ($(this).hasClass("ca_button1")) {
        t.find("a").css("background-color", "#0F0");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("ca_button")) {
        t.find("a").css("background-color", "#F00");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What are the 1 case and the 2 case?

Comment: please see the http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/8/ , there you can see 1.case and 2.case

Comment: You want to make the button in case1 like case2? Think something is getting lost in translation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `t.find("a")`.

In your first case there is no `a` as a child of element with class `ca_button` or `ca_button``.

In your code you have click event registered for `.ca_button` and ``` .ca_button``, so the ```t`will be pointing to that, then in the code where you are changing the color you are looking for a`a` element as the child of the clicked target.

This case does not match in case 1.

```
$(".ca_button, .ca_button1,.button").click(function () {

    var t = $(this);

    $par = t.parent();

    $par.find(".ca_button, .ca_button1").css("background-color", "#bababa");

    var t1 = t.is('a') ? t : t.find('a');

    if (t.hasClass("ca_button1")) {
        t1.css("background-color", "#0F0");
    } else if (t.hasClass("ca_button")) {
        t1.css("background-color", "#F00");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mwsvP/18/)

Comment: I integrated yur code into mine but you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/SVPY2/1/ Its not what I need... but thanks!

Comment: just like I want but now on hover what is defined in css not work :) but very very thanks, I will solve css hover myself!

Answer (score 2):

Change your html from this:

```
<div>PRICE - 1.case
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ca_button" onClick="setQuality(-100, 'price_quality', '{$lang501}/{$lang502}');">Disadvantage</a>
<a class="button">Average</a>
```

Advantage

to this:

```
<div>PRICE - 1.case
<div class="ca_button"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ca_button" onClick="setQuality(-100, 'price_quality', '{$lang501}/{$lang502}');">Disadvantage</a>
    </div>
<a class="button">Average</a>
```

Advantage

Comment: no :) I need to change JS code to work like buttons on 2.case without changing HTML, just JS :)